# change the color of graph points based on condition in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, plot

I m having MFCC feature matrix "ceps", and having array of suppose 20 points as follows,

```
 sp=[200 400 500 ........7568]
```

and i want  to do comparison between two segments for ex:)comparison of features data value from 1 to 200(one segment) and 200 to 400(second segment). the value of comparison work will be either negative or positive ....i have stored all this value in one vector

```
a=zeros((length(sp)-1),1)
a=a';
cont=0;
for i=1:length(sp)-1
cont=cont+1;

if cont==1
ceps1=ceps(:,1:sp(i));
obj=gm.distribution.fit(ceps1',1,'options',options);
y=-obj.NlogL;

else
ceps1=ceps(:,sp(i):sp(i+1));
obj=gm.distribution.fit(ceps1',1,'options',options);
y=-obj.NlogL;

end

ceps2=ceps(:,sp(i):sp(i+1));
[m n]=size(ceps2');
y1=-obj.NlogL;

if cont==1
ceps3=ceps(:,1:sp(i+1));
obj=gm.distribution.fit(ceps3',1,'options',options);
y2=-obj.NlogL;

else
ceps3=ceps(:,sp(i-1):sp(i+1));
obj=gm.distribution.fit(ceps3',1,'options',options);
y2=-obj.NlogL;
end


a(i+1)=y1+y-y2;
end
```

the result of above is vector having all comparison values some are negatives some are positives....In the above programm the iterations are carried out consecutively,for ex: for the first iteration the comparison is in between first segment(ie:from 1 to 200) and second segment(ie: from 200 to 400),in second iteration the comparisaion is in between second segment(200 to 400) and third segment(400 to 500)..

but now i  i want to modify it as, in the first iteration the comparison should be in between first segment(1 to 200)and second segment(200 to 400).the result of comparison will be either positive or negative .

CASE1:
if it is negative make that point green and move for second iteration in which we will do comparison between second segment(200 to 400)and third segment(400 to 500)

CASE2:
if that result is positive we will keep that point as green olny but now for the next iteration the comparison is in between first segment(1 to 400) and second segment(400 to 500).

the sp vector have 20 values,now i plotted that 20 values on a graph by giving properties to each point.

```
figure
plot(sp,'--rs','markeredgecolor','k','markerfacecolor','g','markersize','2');
```

[image]
now i do the processing on each point as above ,the result of that will be either positive or negative.
if the result is negative then i need to change the color property of that point which is processed.
if it is positive then it should retain  the same.

so i need a graph,where the negative value points should be in red,and all others(positive values pts) should be green.

finally it should discard all green points from the graph

how do i do this...

Answer (score 1):

I've coded up a simple example demonstrating how to change the points colour based on its value in a loop.

```
t = 0:0.03:3;
y = sin(2*pi.*t);

figure; hold on;
plot(t,y,'k');
grid;

for i=1:length(x)

    %Select color
    if y(i)<0
        mycolor = 'r';
    else
        mycolor = 'g';
    end

    plot(t(i), y(i), 'sk','markersize',8,'markerfacecolor',mycolor);

end
```

Or you could do it in a more typical MATLAB fashion:

```
idx_neg = (y<0);
idx_pos = ~(idx_neg);
x_neg = x(idx_neg);
y_neg = y(idx_neg);
x_pos = x(idx_pos);
y_pos = y(idx_pos);
figure;
plot(x_neg,y_neg,'sk','markersize',8,'markerfacecolor','r');
plot(x_pos,y_pos,'sk','markersize',8,'markerfacecolor','g');
```

You should easily be able to work this into your code, but I'll leave that to you!

**Output:**

[image: Coloured sine wave]

---

Rather than discard all the green points from the graph when your done, why don't you just plot only the red points.